# extract specific row with numbers over N

Tags: dataframe, awk

I have a dataframe like this

```
1  3  MAPQ=0;CT=3to5;SRMAPQ=60
2  34  MAPQ=60;CT=3to5;SRMAPQ=67
4  56  MAPQ=67;CT=3to5;SRMAPQ=50
5  7  MAPQ=44;CT=3to5;SRMAPQ=61
```

with using awk (or others)

I want to extract rows with only SRMAPQ over 60.

This means the output is

```
2  34  MAPQ=60;CT=3to5;SRMAPQ=67
5  7  MAPQ=44;CT=3to5;SRMAPQ=61
```

> update: "SRMAPQ=60" can be anywhere in the line,
> MAPQ=44;CT=3to5;SRMAPQ=61;DT=3to5

Comment: What did you try with Awk and how did it fail?

Comment: @Inian I had no idea of using > or < in awk, especially with specific string attached like SRMAPQ=60. so I tried

awk '{if ( match($3,/SRMAPQ\=6/) && match($3,/SRMAPQ\=7/)) ; else {print $0}}'

like this, but I know this is not the right way..

Comment: Don't know if you ever have `SRMAPQ=6`, which would cause your method to fail. Try to extract the value using [method described here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/555127/awk-extract-the-actual-value-of-a-regexp-pattern-match). Then compare the value to your set minimum and print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to extract the value out of `SRMAPQ` separately and do the comparison. If the format is fixed like above, just use `=` as the field separator and access the last field using `$NF`

```sh
awk -F= '$NF > 60' file
```

Or if `SRMAPQ` can occur anywhere in the line (as updated in the comments), use a generic approach

```sh
awk 'match($0, /SRMAPQ=([0-9]+)/){ l = length("SRMAPQ="); v = substr($0, RSTART+l, RLENGTH-l) } v > 60' file
```

Comment: Thanks, actually I have another question. What if SRMAP=60 is not at the end? The dataframe  I asked for is a simple form. How about "1  3 MAPQ=0;CT=3to5;SRMAPQ=60;GT=100;DT=40"

Comment: awk 'match($0, /SRMAPQ=([0-9]+)/){ l = length("SRMAPQ="); v = substr($0, RSTART+l, RLENGTH-l) } int(v) > 60' would be better. I tried with my own data but without int(), MAPQ=7 or MAPQ=8 was extracted too.

Comment: @SGKwon I did not run into such issues during the test. If you are testing this on a different input, please update it to the question

Answer (score 0):

I would use GNU `AWK` following way let `file.txt` content be

```
1  3  MAPQ=0;CT=3to5;SRMAPQ=60
2  34  MAPQ=60;CT=3to5;SRMAPQ=67;SOMETHING=2
4  56  MAPQ=67;CT=3to5;SRMAPQ=50
5  7  MAPQ=44;CT=3to5;SRMAPQ=61
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="SRMAPQ="}$2>60' file.txt
```

output

```
2  34  MAPQ=60;CT=3to5;SRMAPQ=67;SOMETHING=2
5  7  MAPQ=44;CT=3to5;SRMAPQ=61
```

Note: added SOMETHING to test if it would work when SRMAPQ is not last. Explantion: I set `FS` to `SRMAPQ=` thus what is before that becomes first field (`$1`) and what is behind becomes second field (`$2`). In 2nd line this is `67;SOMETHING=2` with which GNU `AWK` copes by converting its' longmost prefix which constitute number in this case `67`, other lines have just numbers. Disclaimer: this solution assumes that all but last field have trailing `;`, if this does not hold true please test my solution fully before usage.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*